# In Excel, without using VBA, how can a formula sum over a range of cells containing both numbers and texts representing numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a formula, or function, or combination of functions to SUM over a range of cells, some containing numbers and some containing texts representing numbers? In other words, how do we convert texts in a range of cells to numbers before performing the sum over that range of cells, in one formula, and without the use of VBA?

For instance, I have a range F11 to G11, and F11 has the *text* "43" in it and G11 has the *number* 2 in it. How do you use a formula to make the sum(F11:G11) come up to 45 and not 2 ?

Comment: Sometimes that there's no answer is an answer, and it might be useful for the next person with the same issue. Defacing your answer is not the way

Comment: Just add a double unary in front of the range. eg: `=SUM(--F11:G11)`. Excel will convert the text values to numbers.

Comment: You ought to post that as an answer @RonRosenfeld

Comment: Ron, your formula works as an array formula which in my excel (2016) requires human intervention to get created. The range I use increases per day. The formula I have adjusts for the new range automatically but still the ctrl+shift+enter  would manually be needed. I want it all automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. To avoid the use of arrays (requiring manual ctrl-shift-enter in older excels) the function `SUMPRODUCT` should be used instead of the function `SUM`. Then all the values in the range can be multiplied by 1 (or double negated by "--") to convert them to numbers before they are summed up:

```
           =SUMPRODUCT(1*F11:G11)
```

Or:

```
           =SUMPRODUCT(--F11:G11)
```

So @Ron Rosenfeld's suggestion was indeed the answer but for older excels use `SUMPRODUCT` instead of `SUM`.

This has no human intervention in its working! If the range changes with time (like in the case I have), then define a dynamic range by the appropriate use of `OFFSET` function.

Comment: Nice one ,,, +10 ☺

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be solved by SUM with VALUE function.
See the below screenshot.

[image]

F11 is Text format. G11 is number (General).

VALUE function converts TEXT to Numeric and wrap it in SUM.

```
=SUM(VALUE(F11:G11))
```

This works without CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER in my Excel 2021 but in older versions of Excel you may need to create an Array Formula by simultaneously pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER from within the formula bar. The formula will automatically enclose in Curly Braces.

Check if this is what you want and if this works for you.

Also make sure to set the format as Numeric or General on the cell where you want to enter this results formula, upfront.

Comment: I cannot use an array formula to do the intermediate manipulation of data before summing is done because the aforementioned range in my excel file increases with time in number of cells. I'm using excel 2016, it requires manually doing ctrl+shift+enter. I've written the formula in a way that corrects itself everyday for the new range, so a new array could be defined, but the manual ctrl+shift+enter (i.e. human intervention) is still in the way.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a built-in formula thatnI know of to do this.

You can take an intermediate range, convert text to numbers into the intermediate range.

Use the Function ISNUMBER to determine what is in a cell. Convert if not a number and do not convert if a number.

Then sum the intermediate range.

This is a simple concept and works without VBA.

As I noted, there is no built-in Excel formula that I know of to do precisely what you want.